# How to execute the command in cronjob to display the output in terminal

Tags: cron

i have a query on cronjob , if i execute a command using cronjob is it possible to display the output in terminal rather than saving in output file .

say for eg

```
 */2 * * * root /bin/ping xx.xx.xx.xx
```

the output should display in the terminal . i tried it doesn't show in the terminal. Anything i need to change in my cronjob .

Thanks in advance
Vinoth

Comment: A cronjob will get executed if there is nobody logged in at all, what would the terminal be then? What happens if I have multiple terminals open? What happens if I am another user, do I still see the output?

Comment: If you want to run a program at a specified time and want to see it's output on terminal then go for script rather cronjob

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, yes i agree your point .

Comment: @SHW Thanks for your inputs, let me do try the thing using script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this.

All `cron` jobs are run in non-interactive shells, there is no terminal attachment. Hence the concept of `/dev/tty` or similar is not available in `cron`.

Comment: So if you do `foo | tee /dev/tty | bar` in a cron job, it will error?

Answer (score 6):

The dirty way could be to redirect the output of your program to the pts file of an already existing terminal.

To know the pts file just type tty command

```
~$ tty  
/dev/pts/19
```

then your crontab would be:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/scripts/script.sh > /dev/pts/19
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enter command in crond like this:

```
*/2 * * * root /bin/ping xx.xx.xx.xx | tee ~/my_output_from_crond.log
```

In terminal type:

```
touch ~/my_output_from_crond.log
tail -f ~/my_output_from_crond.log
```

Now just wait to crond start the command